# Laravel 5 - can not reset password on production server 404 - Not Found

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, password-recovery

Anyone knows why the route '/password/email' returns 404 Not Found error on production server, but works on local?

When user is trying to reset his password by email (https://compariimobiliare.ro/password/reset), the POST URL https://compariimobiliare.ro/password/email gives 404 Not Found error. Same URL works fine on local server, but not on production.

The route is there, I can see it when I run the command:

```
php artisan route:list

POST | password/email | | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest
```

[image]

Laravel default implementation:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        if ($response === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
            return back()->with('status', trans($response));
        }

        // If an error was returned by the password broker, we will get this message
        // translated so we can notify a user of the problem. We'll redirect back
        // to where the users came from so they can attempt this process again.
        return back()->withErrors(
            ['email' => trans($response)]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show code of method `sendResetLinkEmail` in controller `ForgotPasswordController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have POST route for password/email.
Do you have a GET route for password/email as well? 
You are getting 404 because it is trying to access GET route.

Comment: That's the strange part, the form uses POST action, but I get a 404 Not found GET error ... maybe some strange redirect... Trying to access "https://compariimobiliare.ro/password/email" using Postman, with POST request, I get the same 404 not found error.

Comment: How are you handling the POST request in Controller? Do you redirect user on success form submision? Are you able to share your code on App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail

Comment: Nothing custom, I use the default laravel implementation, see the question description with the code.

Comment: Hi Andrei, This seems like an issue with your NGINX server because if you try any url with /email it gives a 404 page from NGINX server but if you try say /test it gives your custom 404 page. Might be /email has been configured to be used in NGINX server. Just a wild guess

Comment: you are right, I need to see what strange nginx configuration I have that it causing the 404 error on URLs that include 'email' word. Thanks!